# google calendar api with android - delete event

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I would like to delete an event from a calendar with the followoing code:

```
//insertedEntry: I want to delete it.

"client.executeDelete(insertedEntry);" 

in the Class CalendarClient: 
"  public void executeDelete(Entry entry) throws IOException { 
    HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildDeleteRequest(new GenericUrl(entry.getEditLink())); 
    request.execute().ignore(); 
   } "
```

What's wrong?

I'm started to build my model from this "base" (calendar-v2-atom-oauth-sample): 
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg%2Fcalendar-v2-atom-oauth-sample%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fapi%2Fclient%2Fsample%2Fcalendar%2Fv2%2Fmodel

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-provider-tests/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androidbook/androidcalendar/CalendarActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this to EventEntry.java:

```
@Key("@gd:etag")
public String etag;
```

Added this to CalendarClient.java:

```
   public void executeDelete(Entry entry) throws IOException {
        HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildDeleteRequest(new GenericUrl(entry.getEditLink()));
        if (entry instanceof EventEntry) {
            request.headers.ifMatch = ((EventEntry) entry).etag;
        }
        request.execute().ignore();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this as well getting a 403 Forbidden error.

Interesting that CalendarClient.executeDelete works for a CalendarEntry as shown in this example:

http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/calendar/android/CalendarAndroidSample.java

Gonna have to keep digging to find the delete event solution.