# Deletion of Calendar Events of specific app

Tags: android, calendar, uninstallation

I have code which inserts to calendar entry programmatically. It all works fine when it comes to insertion inside calendar API. 
               Problem is when the app is unistalled, the calendar events created by the app doesnt get deleted. What am i missing? Any help would be appreciable  thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you try to clear calendar event at the time uninstalling your app ?

Comment: I cleared the cache and data before uninstallating app from settings. Still i can see calendar events in calendar api related to app

Comment: Visit this link,hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706720/google-calendar-api-with-android-delete-event

Comment: m using content://com.android.calendar/events to insert calendar events locally. the link provided by you is meant for google based  calendar

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
Uri eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");  // or "content://com.android.calendar/events" 


Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(eventUri, new String[]{"_id"}, "calendar_id = " + calendarId, null, null); // calendar_id can change in new versions 

while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventUri, cursor.getInt(0));

contentResolver.delete(deleteUri, null, null);
```

}